# Developed a Menu Component - How to add Sub Menus to the Component

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Menu Component which is used to populate a list of menu items based on the menuObject supplied to the component. I can pass the menuObject to the component and show the menu when clicked on a button.

But how can I show sub-menus when the menuObject is nested with child elements.

I am not sure how to run recursively on the menuObject to construct the sub-menu using Components. Also the sum-menu should be shown only on **mouseEnter** on the item and should be hidden on **mouseLeave** event on the item.

My Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <button {{action "showMenu" bubbles=false }}>DropDown Menu</button>
    {{#if isShowMenu }}  
        {{show-menu menuAction='menuAction' menuObj=menuObj}} 
    {{/if}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/show-menu">
    <div id="showmenudiv" style="position: absolute;z-index:10;left:10px;top:45px;">
    <ul>
        {{#each menuObj}}
            <li class="menuli" {{action 'menuClick' this bubbles=false}}>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </div> 
</script>
```

App.js:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isShowMenu: false
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
actions:{
showMenu: function(){ 
    var menuObj = [
        {'action': 'createFolder', 'name': 'Create Folder', 'children': [ {'action': 'createSubFolder', 'name': 'Create Sub Folder'}]},
        {'action': 'createDocument', 'name': 'Create Document', 'children':[]},
        {'action': 'createSheet', 'name': 'Create Sheet', 'children':[]},
    ];
    this.controller.toggleProperty('isShowMenu');
    this.controller.set('menuObj', menuObj);
}
});
```

JSBin [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qabize/1/)